# No puedo obtener Json en Ionic

Tags: javascript, json, ionic, angular4

Estoy teniendo problemas para obtener los datos de una api propia y leerlos en la app ionic, basicamente no obtengo error, el get se produce en el servidor con codigo 200, pero en la app no recibo nada, gracias por la ayuda

Respuesta JSON

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "username": "Emanuel",
 "email": "emanuel",
 "password": "123",
 "created_at": "2018-01-17T12:04:43.000Z",
 "updated_at": "2018-01-17T12:04:43.000Z"
 }
]
```

rest.js

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
 export class RestProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
   console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
  }

 apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

 getUsers(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users').subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
  });
 }
}
```

home.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {
   this.getUsers();
  }

  users: any;

  getUsers() {
   this.restProvider.getUsers()
   .then(data => {
    this.users = data;
    console.log(this.users);
   });
  }

}
```

home.html

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Probando Rest
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list inset>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
      <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
      <p>{{user.email}}</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estuve revisando tu código, compañero. Sería excelente que nos compartieras lo que traer consigo el `console.log(data)` de `rest.ts`. Lo que puede ayudarte es que en `home.ts` declararas tu variable `users: any` y la inicialices con un array vacio de la siguiente forma:

`users: any[] = [];`

Ya que, `data` trae un array de objetos y los almacenara en tu variable `users` ya inicializada como un array. De esta forma podrás empezar a utilizar los diferentes atributos.

Espero te sirva de algo, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Según el código que enviaste el único es que en:
`rest.js` en el método `getUsers()` no estás devolviendo los parámetros.

```
getUsers(){
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users').subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
         resolve(data); //agrega esta linea
       }, err => {
       console.log(err);
       });
   });
}
```

¿El `console.log` de `rest.js` te imprime algo en consola?

Puedes revisar tu solicitud se recibe bien con la aplicación "POSTMAN" que te muestra como te están llegando los datos.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tambien podrias intentar hacer lo siguiente para obtener la promesa:

```
getUsers(){
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/users').toPromise()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el .map

Te dejo un ejemplo de un código que hice hace poco

let direccion = this._conexion.Url + "vendedor/pin/" + numero;

```
        this.http.get(direccion)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data =>{
              if(!data){ 
                  Console.log(data)
                 }
```

});

Código completo y comentado en

https://github.com/waleman/EquatePro/tree/master/EquatePro/src/pages/login